# Algorithm that returns the path of one cylce in undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I am trying to construct an algorithm that returns the nodes of a path that make up ONE cycle in an undirected graph (if there is one). What I have so far is performing DFS on the graph until I reach an undiscovered edge leading to a discovered node (at that point I know there is a cycle). But how do I know which path made the cycle. If I use a stack/queue to record my path, how does that help me? Say I start from a node which is not part of the path of a cycle, how would I later know to take it out of the stack/queue?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can make that work. When you hit an undiscovered edge leading to a discovered node, walk back along the edges until you get back to the same node, and just those edges and nodes you crossed will be part of your cycle. However, will this method necessarily find any cycles? I'm not sure.

Comment: Yea, but how do I "walk" back?

Comment: if you add nodes when you walk them, just pop them out ... otherwise, you can create your own type which will hold whatever information you need ...

Comment: Yea, but when I walk them, my path can be very jagged. I can branch off into a place where there are no cycles (on my way to finding a cycle), how do I know not to include that path.

Comment: do you need *any* cycle or there are some requirements (it has to start/end in particular node; has to visit all nodes etc)?

Comment: any cycle. no specific starting node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform the `DFS` record which is the node you came from when you visited each node. Call this `parent` for the new node. Now when you reach an edge `(u, v)` that leads to an already visited node `v`, walk up the path made by the parents up to `u`, or up to the source of the `DFS` (denote this `s`).

You will always reach one of the two. If you reach `s`, than perform the same from `v` and you have your cycle - the path from `u` to `s` the path from `s` to `v` and the new edge. If you reach `v` you again have a cycle - the path from `u` to `v` and than the new edge.

Comment: @AYR it will be nice exercise for you to come up with it on your own. I believe my answer is detailed enough for this.

Comment: If I understood your algorithm correctly, I do not need to make use of any stack other than the stack used for DFS itself.

Comment: You need one additional array to stack the parents for each node. Also I would use one more stack for the reconstruction of the cycle( the reconstruction of the path to `v` or `s`), but you can make do without it too.

Comment: @AYR While traversing the graph, you just have to keep track from which node given node has been **directly** reached. If you consider a node *v*, for all yet not visited neighbors of *v* remember *v* as the node from which they were reached. Once the cycle is closed (meaning you hit already visited node) just go back by the *remembered* path.